# Microsoft graph explorer - create user & update sign in username /email

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I tried to create update login username or email through Microsoft graph explorer but I am unable to do both actions. Probably the json data I am supplying might not be in correct format.
I am logged in with admin account, used PATCH method and successfully updated information by supplying below codes:

```
{
    "displayName": "AAAlica",
    "givenName": "Mews",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "P@ssword!"
    }
}
```

I don't know what attributes and values should I provide in order to change login username/email address. I tried different format like

```
{
    "displayName": "AAAnamika",
    "givenName": "MMews",
    "userPrincipalName": "newusername@mycompanydomain@onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

and always getting error.

References:

- graph explorer: [Microsoft graph explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer#/)
- documentation: [Microsoft graph api documentation](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update)

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the userPrincipalName in your post is invalid which contains two `@`.

The correct format should be like `newusername@mycompanydomain.onmicrosoft.com`. Here is the detail description for the UPN property:

*The UPN is an Internet-style login name for the user based on the Internet standard RFC 822. By convention, this should map to the user's email name. The general format is alias@domain, where domain must be present in the tenant’s collection of verified domains.*

Comment: Yes the error was in UPN your solution works. I tried to follow the microsoft graph documentation for creating user  [https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users].
where it mentioned:
`"userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value@onmicrosoft.com"`
in the UPN value.

Comment: That's a bug in the docs.  We should fix that.  Can you file a new doc issue for this on GitHub here please: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues.  For the password reset attempt (through Graph Explorer) can you update with the actual full error message that you see please?  Also, is the signed in user (to Graph Explorer) a tenant admin?

Comment: Thank you @DanKershaw-MSFT The issue of updating password is solved by elevating the `GraphScopes` to `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`. 
I will report the issue for the documentation into github.